# Binary parameter

Tags: python, binary, docplex

How can I write a binary variable as a parameter using python docplex?

```
Y[k,m,t]=(1, if participant will have meal m in restaurant k on day t
          0, otherwise)
```

Comment: do you have CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.7 or 12.8?

Comment: I have CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.8